# How to get path of image, selected from gallery in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, nsurl

In obj-c with using image picker, I could get path of image with this:

```
NSURL* localUrl = (NSURL *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
```

but when I try this code in swift :

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
    })
        var path : NSURL  = editingInfo.valueForKeyPath("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage") as NSURL
... }
```

it crashes and say

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

so, how can I get path of an image in swift?

Comment: editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage

Answer (score 2):

you lost this line?

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
```

if you set

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
```

editingInfo will always be nil

Comment: oh! you get wrong key? it's "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL" not UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage

Answer (score 2):

hi i got the image url using below code .It works fine in swift 2.0

let path = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL

Answer (score 0):

You are perhaps using a different dictionary? Above it is `info`, later you are using `editingInfo`. Explain how you extract your dictionaries with complete code.